# Vertx , Node or Play for calling multiple webservice asynchrously

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, playframework, vert.x

I am developing a project and In this project  I need calling multiple concurent web services ( least 5 webservice) asynchrously. 
 For that  , whcih framework can be used  Vertx , node , or  Play

thanks

Comment: Node.js and Play will both consume multiple web services asynchronously (I've not worked with Vertex). I guess the bigger question to choose between them is what you plan to do with the web service return?

Comment: Posting as a comment since this points to my own blog, but you might find a screencast I did helpful: http://www.jamesward.com/2013/10/30/intro-to-reactive-composition-with-the-typesafe-reactive-platform  This screencast covers how to do Reactive Composition (multiple async & non-blocking requests) with Play Framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Play documentation is not so good. If you are thinking to implement in scala play can be good option, but for java you may not find it so great as few things are not supported in Java (Eg to write a body parser of your own you need to use scala)

Nodejs can be a good choice however, in nodejs utilizing all the cpu cores is hard. There is a framework jxcore which claims to have a solution for this, but, I have not used it.

Vert.X IMO can be a good framework, it makes good use of all cpu cores, provides N event loops. Optionally,  you can use worker thread pool if you really need to do cpu intensive operation and be responsive.

Answer (score 2):

In play there is too much working out of the box. Node js will be nice if you can lose some time for writing your own tools.

Answer (score 2):

All of these frameworks can be used.

Disclaimer: I work on the Play framework.

Given Play's Scala heritage, even if you're using Java, we provide Promises so that you can reason the flow of making async calls without suffering from what is known as "callback-hell". You may want to consider using promises for Node also... I believe they are available. I think Vert.x may offer something there too. I'm unsure but I don't believe Node and vert.x provide promises out of the box.

You may find this page useful: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaWS

Answer (score 0):

You can use vertx with RxJava module ( https://github.com/vert-x/mod-rxvertx ). You can combine your async results in anyway you want. rxvertx module supports wrappers for EventBus, HttpServer, HttpClient, NetServer, NetClient and Timer.